# enter data in another website and get response back with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fiddler

I want to POST data to http://irsherkat.ssaa.ir/Design/SearchCompanyPublicInfo.aspx with value of for example 10861677542 for #txtNationalCode input. When I use Fiddler to POST request to http://irsherkat.ssaa.ir/hndlr/GeneralHandler.ashx?Id=33 (which posted data was sent to), with this Request Header:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and this Request Body:

```
Request={'ClassTypeName':'TRM.hndlr.Classes.CompanyPublicInfoController','MethodName':'SearchData','DataParamType':'TRM.hndlr.TRMTypeDefinition.CompanyPublicInfo.CompanyPublicInfoSerchParam','MainEntityType':'','DataParam':'{\'Nationalcode\':\'10861677542\',\'Registernumber\':\'\',\'UnitId\':null,\'CompanyTypeId\':\'0\'}'}
```

I get 200 success result but when I want to do that with this C# code:

```
public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://irsherkat.ssaa.ir/hndlr/GeneralHandler.ashx?Id=33");

        var postData = "Request={'ClassTypeName':'TRM.hndlr.Classes.CompanyPublicInfoController','MethodName':'SearchData','DataParamType':'TRM.hndlr.TRMTypeDefinition.CompanyPublicInfo.CompanyPublicInfoSerchParam','MainEntityType':'','DataParam':'{\'Nationalcode\':\'10861677542\',\'Registernumber\':\'\',\'UnitId\':null,\'CompanyTypeId\':\'0\'}'}";
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        return new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    }
```

It gives me this error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

Comment: Just use Fiddler again and compare request you're sending with C# application with request sent from fiddler itself. Probably you're missing something.

Comment: Probably you need double backslashes in `postData` variable

Comment: Thanks,the problem was single backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `"Request="` from `postData` value.